Why doesn't my manually entered double value match the expected value in C?
Question:
As a beginner, i am curious about memory architecture and how values get stored in memory, so I tried this code. Nothing else.
I'm trying to manually input byte values to create a specific double value using scanf in C. However, the resulting double value doesn't match my expectations. Here is what I'm doing:
First, the working example:
This program prints each byte value from the 8 bytes allocated to a double.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double a = 18446744073709551616.0;
    printf("value=%lf\n", a);
    int i;
    char *b = (char*)&a;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
       printf("%d byte (%p)value: <%d>\n", i + 1, b, *b);
       b++;
    }
    return 0;
}

Output:
value=18446744073709551616.000000
1 byte (0x7ffda3f173f8)value: <0>
2 byte (0x7ffda3f173f9)value: <0>
3 byte (0x7ffda3f173fa)value: <0>
4 byte (0x7ffda3f173fb)value: <0>
5 byte (0x7ffda3f173fc)value: <0>
6 byte (0x7ffda3f173fd)value: <0>
7 byte (0x7ffda3f173fe)value: <-16>
8 byte (0x7ffda3f173ff)value: <67>

This makes sense when you convert all these values to binary and read it in little endian format, which gives me the IEEE-754 standard representation of
18446744073709551616.000000 conversion is:
1st byte value (0) which in binary -> (00000000)
2nd byte value (0) which in binary -> (00000000)
3rd byte value (0) which in binary -> (00000000)
4th byte value (0) which in binary -> (00000000)
5th byte value (0) which in binary -> (00000000)
6th byte value (0) which in binary -> (00000000)
7th byte value (-16) which in binary -> (11110000)
8th byte value (67) which in binary -> (01000011)

Now, the problematic code:
I tried to input this value manually using scanf with the following code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double a;
    int i;
    char *b = (char*)&a;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
       printf("Enter %d byte value: ", i + 1);
       scanf("%d", b);
       b++;
    }
    printf("Final value: %lf\n", a);
    return 0;
}

Input:
1 byte value: 0
2 byte value: 0
3 byte value: 0
4 byte value: 0
5 byte value: 0
6 byte value: 0
7 byte value: -16
8 byte value: 67

Output:

Final value: 0.000000

Question:
Why doesn't this code produce the same double value as the first example? How can I correctly input the byte values to achieve the same double value?

Safer (and simpler, and quicker) to observe the memory in a debugger than to attempt to write code to inspect the representation.  As here you are then required to get that inspection code right (you could use the debugger for that too ;-) ).

@Clifford Thanks for your advice .I'm beginner and I don't know how to use gdb.

Yes... gdb - not the fun debugger!  There are plenty of easier "ins" with gdb such as IDE integrations and stand-alone UIs.

@Clifford okay I will try that.

You are using the wrong format specifier. In order to ensure that the input is read as a char, you need the %hhd. Specifically, your line scanf("%d", b); scans an integer and stores in a char type variable, making the behaviour undefined. Recall that int and char have different bytes. char is 1 byte and int is usually 4 (depending on the compiler)
For completeness, the code and outputs are shown below:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double a;
    int i;
    char *b = (char*)&a;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
       printf("Enter %d byte value: ", i + 1);
       scanf("%hhd", b);
       b++;
    }
    printf("Final value: %lf\n", a);
    return 0;
}

Output:
/tmp/E9Olq2nOoS.o
Enter 1 byte value: 0
Enter 2 byte value: 0
Enter 3 byte value: 0
Enter 4 byte value: 0
Enter 5 byte value: 0
Enter 6 byte value: 0
Enter 7 byte value: -16
Enter 8 byte value: 67
Final value: 18446744073709551616.000000


Yeah i too figured out the answer after asked the question .but you answered the question before i answer the question. So i accepted your answer as correct.Thank you so much.

thanks, this happens all the time; that is the beauty of asking questions using a minimum reproducible example. Often we find the answers when asking the question in a detailed manner since it takes a non-trivial amount of effort to ask the question itself.
